# Scrollspy just active the last button of the navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

It just active the last button of the navbar.

I tried to use different values to data-offset but seems to not work.

```
    <body id="page-top" class="index">

    <nav id = "menu"class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Test site</a>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#servers">section 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#about">section 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
<div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#menu" data-offset="0">
    <section id="servers">
....

    </section>

    <section id="about" class="success text-center about-section">
          ....
      </div>
      </section>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hunterfps/h1akyg1m/2/

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the Bootstrap documentation:

> To easily add scrollspy behavior to your topbar navigation, add `data-spy="scroll"` to the element you want to spy on (most typically this would be the `<body>`). Then add the data-target attribute with the ID or class of the parent element of any Bootstrap .nav component.

In your example, you didn't apply the scrollspy to the body, but to a `div` and the navigation was outside of that. If you apply the scrollspy to the `body` tag instead, this will now work:

```
<body id="page-top" class="index" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#menu">
    <nav id = "menu"class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        ...
    </nav>
    <section id="servers">
        ...
    </section>
    <section id="about" class="success text-center about-section">
        ...
    </section>
</body>
```